# Openshift CLI :: How to set environment variables that refer to application metadata?

Tags: openshift, openstack

I am trying to set environment variables to `deployment config` -- these environment variables will be referring to `application metadata` for the values.

I am able to specify in `deployment_config.yaml` as below:

```
 env:
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

How do I set environment variables similarly through cli using :
`oc set env`, as I did not find options to specify `fieldRef` & `fieldPath`.

I am looking for set these kind of environment properties using `cli`.

Please share if you know any alternatives.

Comment: You could only make the change after the deployment from the command line by using ``oc edit`` and manually changing it, or using ``oc patch``.

Comment: Hi Graham, I am trying to add these properties just after creating deployment config. I'm not trying to edit a running deployment. Will try your suggestions and update here.. Thank you.

Comment: I have gone through the man pages and these commands `oc edit` and `oc patch`  doesn't seem to address this kind of env. setting.

Comment: Creating a deployment config means your application would also normally then be running unless you have also disabled triggers so the deployment doesn't happen. When you edit the deployment config, the change to the config will trigger a new deployment of your application with the changes in the environment unless you have disabled the trigger for that as well.

Comment: The ``oc edit`` and ``oc patch`` commands allow you to make any sort of change to an existing deployment config, so not sure why you don't think they could be used.

Comment: I am referring to a deployment config that was just created using `oc create dc` command through cli. It does not have any triggers. My question is specific to setting environment variables that refer to metadata for the values.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but using `oc patch` you can use something like:

```
$ oc patch dc myapp --type=json --patch '
[
  { 
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env",
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "POD_NAME",
            "valueFrom": {
                "fieldRef": {
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.name"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "POD_NAMESPACE",
            "valueFrom": {
                "fieldRef": {
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.namespace"
                }
            }
        }
     ]
  }
]
'
```

Where there is an existing `env` array, needs to be a bit different and likely need to add a single entry at a time to end of the existing array. See:

- http://jsonpatch.com/

for details of `jsonpatch` format.